# sprintf() - left-aligning several units within one placeholder

Tags: c

I'm decoding cpu opcodes and their arguments that are separated by a placeholder.

This works perfectly with *one* left-side unit by providing `myop            a0`

```
sprintf(dest, "%-16s%s", opcode, arg);
```

But when I have opcodes that consist of *several* units like this `myop.w.s       a0` where the first 3 units need to be on the left side of the placeholder, and the arg goes after it, what is the way to have them behave like here

```
sprintf(dest, "%s.%s.%s\t\t%s", opcode, param1, param2, arg);
```

but without the use of tabs?

There's also a way to do `sprintf()` twice, at first I create a combined string `"myop.w.s"` and then during the second `sprintf()` I pad it, but I'm curious if there are other solutions.

Comment: Yup, I don't believe there's any way to do that all inside a single call to `sprintf` - you'll need some variant of your suggested solution.

Comment: Try `sprintf(dest, "%s.%s.%s%16s", opcode, param1, param2, arg)`.

Comment: @barakmanos won't this ignore the size of the first 3 and just add 16 spaces no matter what?

Comment: @barakmanos - That's not what the OP is looking for - (s)he wants the first three fields to be jointly padded up to 16 characters.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: In that case, (s)he should start with `sprintf(format, "%%s.%%s.%%s%%%ds",16-strlen(opcode)-strlen(param1)-strlen(param2)-2)` followed by `sprintf(dest, format, opcode, param1, param2, arg)`.

Comment: @barakmanos: Indeed.  Or more simply: `sprintf(combined, "%s.%s.%s", opcode, param1, param2); sprintf("%-16s%s", combined, arg);`.

Comment: Another variation: `int len = sprintf(dest, "%s.%s.%s", opcode, param1, param2)`; sprintf(dest, "%*s", 16-len, arg);` This avoids extra `strlen` calls and doesn't require additional memory.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - You seem to be printing to `dest` twice - that's a bug.  Do you mean something like `sprintf(dest + len, "%*s", 16-len, arg);`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes I do.

Answer (score 2):

Print the first 3 strings and the spacing as needed

```
snprintf(dest, 16, "%s.%s.%s%16s", opcode, param1, param2, "");
strcpy(dest + 16, arg);
```